# Retrieving Facebook Post Information via CURL

Tags: facebook, graph, command-line-interface

For a long time now we have been successfully reading social stats (likes, shares, etc) for posts using basic curl url calls like this but this now gives errors.

For example url: https://www.facebook.com/638487527928707/posts/818905003220291

Where we used

$page_id = 638487527928707
$post_id = 818905003220291

from the link above

Now with the same code we run into errors:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{$page_id}/?fields=fan_count.summary(true).limit(0)&access_token={$facebook_access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/%7B$page_id%7D/?fields=fan_count.summary(true).limit(0)&access_token=%7B$facebook_access_token%7D)

Gives: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '638487527928707' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{$post_id}/?fields=from,to&access_token={$facebook_access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/%7B$post_id%7D/?fields=from,to&access_token=%7B$facebook_access_token%7D)

Gives: "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher" - no matter what api version we use

Our App permissions havent changed, accesstoken is valid (tested via Graph Explorer) and for some other posts this same code is still working. So wondering what could be causing these errors? Has the way IDs are created changed?

Thanks

Comment: What type of access token are you using? What permissions does it actually include?

Comment: tried with user token (pages_show_list, public_profile, instagram_basic, pages_read_engagement)  as well as app token (advanced level for: oembed, pages publiccontent, instagram public content, public profile, default: public page meta data access, business asset user profile access, pages)

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/638487527928707` only leads me to an error page, so if that page ID is actually correct, I would assume its visibility is somehow limited? What is the relation of the user whose token you are using, to the page - do they have admin access?

Comment: calling via web a profile by id has never worked and is not the problem here

Comment: Well I am trying to help you figure out _what_ the problem is here, so please don't give me attitude for it. For normal, publicly available pages this _does_ work - so what you are having there, presumably must be something else then.

Comment: didnt mean that, sorry. yeah figured the problem is some kind of access right or maybe blocking setting in the authors page?

Comment: can you or someone else try with the api to read info about that post and page?

Comment: I am only getting "Unsupported get request" when trying to request any details via the page ID - but since I do not have any app with the page public content / metadata access features approved, that result is only to be expected. Does your user have any role on the page, or are you trying to read public information of a page they do not actually have any relation with here?